# Android line wrapping trim extra space

Tags: android, textview

I have an Android TextView which I'm trying to display some multi-line text. I want the first line to be centered, and all of the other lines to be centered as well, but left-aligned with the first line. When wrapping the text, the TextView goes as wide as the view will allow, even though the actual text stopped a while ago. I would like to trim this extra padding space.

Here's a rudimentary ASCII thing that kinda shows what I'm talking about.

```
|     FirstLineOfText     |
|     SecondLine          |
|                         |
|                         |
```

But what I'm getting is more like

```
|    FirstLineOfText    |
|      SecondLine       |
|                       |
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using two textviews. One for the first line and the second for the others in relative layout. Then align the second one to left using android:layout_alignLeft = "idOfFirstTextView".

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not sure if the line would always be wrapping on various devices.